# Why does my Jekyll page display raw front matter?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

I got a template from jekylltheme.org and created a branch in my own repository, hosted it on a GitHub page, and got the "---- layout: home # Index page ----" problem! I am new in this field, what is the problem? Thanks!

- Template source address https://github.com/cotes2020/jekyll-theme-chirpy/
- The address of the branch I created: https://github.com/skywalkergene/skywalkergene.github.io
- Result:

  [image]

I haven't changed any of the code in the repository.

Comment: You have a file `.nojekyll` in your repository, which prevents Jekyll from doing any processing. You have to delete that.

Comment: Then, you have to follow [these instructions](https://chirpy.cotes.page/posts/getting-started/#deployment). You have to switch your build source to "GitHub Actions".

Comment: (At which point the presence of `.nojekyll` doesn't matter any longer.)